# PhantomJS Bypassing Proxy for Certain Hosts

Tags: c#, selenium, phantomjs, http-proxy

The PhantomJSDriverService supports specifying a HTTP proxy server. However there's no way to specify a list of hosts that shouldn't go via the proxy. This feature would be really useful for testing websites that aren't accessible via the proxy server. What can i do to add bypass list

Tried to add in config file but with no success:

```
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy>
      <bypasslist>
        <add address="url"/>
      </bypasslist>
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
```